# The function stops repeating after being repeated six times

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I need the function to be repeated several times (e.g. 10 times) and then stopped, but when you press another button this number cancels and starts counting again. But I can't control the number of times it recurs because this error comes out:
[image]

This is the code I tried to use:

```js
let currentIndex = 0;

function toMove() {
  const slider = document.querySelector('#thumbelina0');
  const element = document.querySelectorAll('span')[currentIndex];
  // there seems to be a hard-coded 10px in your style
  slider.style.marginLeft = parseInt(slider.style.marginLeft) - element.offsetWidth - 10 + 'px';
  currentIndex++;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbelina" style="padding:5px;overflow: hidden;">
  <button class="btnToLeft" onclick="toMovel()"><</button>
  <ul id="thumbelina0" style="padding:0px; width:max-content; text-align:center;display: flex;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 0px;">
    {{images}}
    <li style="padding:5px;width: auto;height: 100px;display: block;"><img src="{{preview_image}}" style="background-image: url({{preview_image}})" style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -5px;" /></li>
    <span id="121"></span> {{end images}}
  </ul>
  <button class="btnToRight" onclick="toMove()">></button>
</div>
```

Comment: If the list that `.querySelectorAll()` returns is shorter than you expect, you'll get that error.

Comment: Also making those `<span>` elements children of the `<ul>` is invalid markup.

Comment: You need to detect when `currentIndex` has reached the end of the list of spans and stop.

Comment: And then how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let currentIndex = 0;
let maxIterations = 10;

function toMove() {
  if (currentIndex === maxIterations) {
    return;
  }
  const slider = document.querySelector('#thumbelina0');
  const element = document.querySelectorAll('span')[currentIndex];
  slider.style.marginLeft = parseInt(slider.style.marginLeft) - element.offsetWidth - 10 + 'px';
  currentIndex += 1;
}
```

Comment: Just like again after pressing only six times the error (parseInt is undefined) comes out

Comment: The `undefined` comes because there are no more `span` elements available. You can check if `index` is increasing by inserting `console.log('index', currentIndex);` at the beginning of `toMove()` function.